# Какой смысл вкладывается в слова "чистое надмножество"?

Tags: c, objective-c

Говорят, что Objective-C это ***чистое надмножество*** языка C. Какой смысл вкладывается в это? Что значит ***надмножество*** в данном контексте? Какие еще примеры таких отношений можно привести (кроме C++ и Objective-C++)?

Например в [этом справочнике](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/17562786/?gclid=CjwKEAjwrIa9BRD5_dvqqazMrFESJACdv27GihXpLP26atXyXLcXXQVuD9X0o-MmcF_AcavUQ2qDQBoC47_w_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: *Говорят* всегда где-то. Не распускайте слухи, приводите источник!

Comment: это значит только одно - что любой валидный си код может быть скомпилирован Objective-C компилятором и он будет делать ровно то, что делал бы код, скомпилированный обычным си компилятором.

Comment: @twone всё, что про вопрос, надо в вопрос, не в комментарии.

Comment: @KoVadim: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: Потому что сейчас набежит толпа "вахтеров", потребует ссылки, скажет, что это не соответствует высоким нормам сайта и тому подобное:)

Comment: @KoVadim переносите в ответ. тут даже ссылку не надо - любая статья про обжС сразу начинается с того, что он написан на основе С с добавлением Smalltalk. если попросят ссылку отправляйте в википедию

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если какой то язык X (технология) является чистым надмножеством Y, то это значит, что программа написаная на Y будет компилироваться компилятором от X и работать без каких-то отличий. В случае языков программирования это также значит, что если пишем код на X, то можно смешивать его (иногда абсолютно свободно) с Y в одном файле.

Вопреки распространненному заблуждению, с++ не является надмножеством чистого си. Есть много примеров кода, когда он либо не будет компилироваться, либо скомпилированный код будет выдавать различные результаты. Классический пример - в си `sizeof('a') == sizeof(int)` (то есть, обычно 4), а в C++ — равенство `sizeof('a') == sizeof(char)` (то есть, обычно 1).